# Regular Expression String Does Not Contain Numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern in a url that does not include a number.

For example:

```
/painters/1-joe-bob/dashboard
```

I would only want to match urls that are the following:

```
/painters
/painters/string
```

If the url includes `/painters/1-something` then there should be no match.

I've been trying the following with no luck:

```
\/{1}(painters|contractors)\/?[^0-9][a-z]*
```

This still matches on `/painters/` or `/contractors/`

Please advise.

Comment: Enclose the `/` and following in `()` with a `*`.  `^\/(painters|contractors)(\/[a-z]+)*$` should do it...

Comment: This still matches on painters and contractors for example /painters/1-joe-bob/dashboard. Is it possible to ensure the whole expression matches?

Comment: If painter or contractors is followed by a /1 (or any number) I do not want to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this regex. It uses a negative lookahead to disallow a match if a number comes after your second forward slash.

```
^\/(painters|contractors)\/(?![0-9])
```

Note that if you don't want number anywhere in the string you can use a negative lookahead right at the beginning.

```
^(?!.*[0-9])\/(painters|contractors)\/
```

This construct will disallow any string containing numbers.

Comment: Thank you. This worked with only a slight change: (?!.*[0-9])\/(painters|contractors)\/?